# How to make Container widget take only the required space in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a chat application using flutter. In that, I have to create a chat screen containing messages. I want each message container to take only the required space. For example: Short message, short container width & Long message, long container. Currently, it's taking full space of the `Column` container no matter what's the length of the message.

As a side note, I have tried wrapping the message container inside flexible but it didn't work at all.

Here's my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:memomessenger/Services/Chats.dart';
import 'package:memomessenger/Services/Constants.dart';
import 'package:memomessenger/Services/Types/Chat.dart';
import 'package:memomessenger/Services/Types/ChatsActivity.dart';
import 'package:memomessenger/Services/User.dart';

Widget buildMessageWidget(
    BuildContext context, Message message, String currentUserId) {
  final bool isFromCurrentUser = message.senderId == currentUserId;
  return LimitedBox(
    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .75,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(
            isFromCurrentUser ? 0 : messageBorderRadius,
          ),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(
            isFromCurrentUser ? messageBorderRadius : 0,
          ),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(messageBorderRadius),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(messageBorderRadius),
        ),
        color: isFromCurrentUser ? themeAccentColor[500] : Colors.cyan,
      ),
      child: Align(
        alignment:
            isFromCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          message.text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: isFromCurrentUser ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildChatMessagesUI(BuildContext context, List<Message> messages) {
  final String currentUserId = currentUser.value.id;
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
      children: messages.reversed.map((Message message) {
        return buildMessageWidget(context, message, currentUserId);
      }).toList(),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildMessageInputUI({@required String chatId}) {
  final String currentUserId = currentUser.value.id;
  return TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Enter your email',
    ),
    onChanged: (String message) {
      sendMessage(chatId, Message(text: message, senderId: currentUserId));
    },
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter some text';
      }
      return null;
    },
    autofocus: true,
    autocorrect: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  );
}

class ChatActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  final String chatId;

  ChatActivity({@required this.chatId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder<Map<String, Chat>>(
                    stream: chatActivityChatList,
                    initialData: {},
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, Chat>> data) {
                      if (data.hasData && data.data[chatId] != null) {
                        return buildChatMessagesUI(
                            context, data.data[chatId].messages);
                      } else {
                        return Text("No Data");
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                buildMessageInputUI(chatId: chatId),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change column MainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min which will behave as wrap_content. Let me know if this works for you, I will then post the full answer.

Comment: Nope, same result! Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean it's taking up the full width of the `Column`?  Height shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/D35N68m.jpeg this is the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Align` widget sizes itself to its incoming constraints if bounded, and your `Container` with a decoration is placed around it.  This means the decoration will cover the entire width of the column.  To fix this, the `DecoratedBox` (produced by  `Container`) needs to be a descendant of `Align` instead.

Another problem you may have noticed is that `LimitedBox` does nothing if the incoming constraint is already bounded.  In order to tighten the existing bound, you will need to provide `constraints` in your `Container` (or equivalently, a `ConstrainedBox` widget).  `FractionallySizedBox` might also be worth considering.

```dart
Widget buildMessageWidget(
    BuildContext context, Message message, String currentUserId) {
  final bool isFromCurrentUser = message.senderId == currentUserId;
  return Align(
    alignment:
      isFromCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .75
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(
            isFromCurrentUser ? 0 : messageBorderRadius,
          ),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(
            isFromCurrentUser ? messageBorderRadius : 0,
          ),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(messageBorderRadius),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(messageBorderRadius),
        ),
        color: isFromCurrentUser ? themeAccentColor[500] : Colors.cyan,
      ),
      child: Text(
        message.text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: isFromCurrentUser ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts! God bless you!!